# Use prerender.io with my existing nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, prerender, laravel-forge

I am trying to implement [Dynamic Rendering for google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/dynamic-rendering#implement).

I have a server on Laravel Forge for serving a Nuxt.js application and I want to use prerender.io

Prerender.io gives an nginx config to use but my current config seems a lot different from it. I don't have any experience with it so I am asking for help if there is anyone who can help.

This is my current nginx config

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/beta.example.com/before/*;


map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    "text/html"                 epoch;
    "text/html; charset=utf-8"  epoch;
    default                     off;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name beta.example.com;
    root /home/forge/beta.example.com/dist;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/beta.example.com/50331/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/beta.example.com/50331/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    charset utf-8;

    gzip            on;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/beta.example.com/server/*;

    location / {
        expires $expires;

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout          1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000; # set the adress of the Node.js
    }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/beta.example.com-error.log error;

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/beta.example.com/after/*;
```

This is how it should look like
https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802

My main question basically is what happens to the current `location /` block.

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to achieve your goal:

- Nuxt.js has its own pre-render solution. you could find it [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide#server-rendered-universal-ssr-).
- If you still want to use prerender.io, here is an example:

I saw that your Nginx is proxying **all** traffic to `http://127.0.0.1:3000`, which is presumably a backend written in Node.js. So you could directly update your `location /` block to use prerender.io to catch everything.

```
...
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token YOUR_TOKEN;

    set $prerender 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }
    if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }

    #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    if ($prerender = 1) {
        #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
        set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
        rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
        proxy_pass http://$prerender;
    }
    try_files @backend;
}

location @backend {
    expires $expires;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout          1m;
    proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
    proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000; # set the adress of the Node.js
}
...
```